# Mod re write breaking url

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Update I have re- done the code and folder system of my mod re write on localhost still nothing

the link only shows like this

> http://localhost/cms/member/profile.php?member=10308

my entire .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^cms/member/([^/]*)$ /cms/member/profile.php?member=$1 [L]
```

when i click on the link it does nothing. if i change in the browser to

> http://localhost/cms/member/10308

it says page cannot be found.

Update the problem was this peice of code causing it to not display right

```
<?php


    if(empty($_GET['member']) || $_GET['member'] <1000 ) {
        redirect(ROOT_URI);
        exit;
    }

?>
```

But i need this code.

the url will work but i need to type it in manually it wont automatically change the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using an .htaccess file which is placed under the directory "cms", you should use the following directives:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^member/([^/][0-9]*)$ member/profile.php?member=$1
```

This will send the request `http://localhost/cms/member/(any-number)` to `http://localhost/cms/member/profile.php?member=(any-number)`

Note:

1. mod_rewrite should be enabled.
2. In httpd.conf (or apache2.conf), replace `AllowOverride None` by `AllowOverride All` to enable .htaccess
3. Restart Apache server.

Comment: nidhi i used the above and it does nothing

Comment: @Amoro is mod_rewrite enabled? If you are using the virtual host block, remember to restart apache.

Comment: nidhi i have it in the cms folder when i click on the link it redirects to http://localhost/cms/

Comment: @Amoro Do you mean when you access `http://localhost/cms/member/0403` it is redirecting to `http://localhost/cms` ? The rule does not have a [R] flag, so it should not redirect. You should see the same URL `http://localhost/cms/member/0403` on the browser. Only the request will be forwarded internally to profile.php. Is there any other rule in the .htaccess file, which is causing this redirection?

Comment: nidhi I figured out what was wrong i got it to somewhat work i am updating question..